# Indy IdHTTP.Get() Socket Error 10038 and then 10060

Tags: android, delphi, winapi, firemonkey, indy

I use this code on a Firemonkey App in XE6 and it works fine.
Now I am trying to use it at work with XE8 for a new app, but I get `e.Message = 'Connection Timed Out'` with both error codes `10060` and `10038` and I simply can't understand why? I tested inside the network and in my 3G connection.

```
    try
    { conecta no servidor para procurar o documento }
      Log.Lines.Add('Internet: Iniciando Protocolo');
      Cloud := TIdHTTP.Create(Self);
      Log.Lines.Add('Internet: Tentando Conectar...');
      DocumentText := Cloud.Get(Format('http://alcantara.net.br:80/ristretto/index.php?ac=dl&&ln=%s&&lk=%s&&dn=%s&&dk=%s',[LoginNX,LoginKX,DocumentNX,DocumentKX]));
      Log.Lines.Add('Internet: Sucesso ao Conectar!');
      Cloud.Free;
      NewDocument := (Length(DocumentText) = 7) and (LeftStr(DocumentText, 7) = '@newdoc');
    { decodifica o documento e começa a edição }
      lblStatus.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
      if NewDocument then
      begin
        lblStatus.Text := 'Novo: ' + DocumentNS;
        DocumentContent.Lines.Clear;
      end
      else
      begin
        lblStatus.Text := DocumentNS;
        DocumentContent.Lines.Text := Alcantara.Whisper.SSCM.SSCMR(DocumentText, LoginNX+LoginKX, DocumentNX+DocumentKX);
      end;
      DocumentOpened := True;
    finally
      if not DocumentOpened then
        Log.Lines.Add('Documento: Nenhum')
      else
        if NewDocument then
          Log.Lines.Add('Documento: Novo (Vazio)')
        else
          Log.Lines.Add('Documento: ' + DocumentNS);
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
    begin
      lblStatus.Text := E.Message;
      Log.Lines.Add('Erro: ' + E.Message);
      lblStatus.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but this should be wrapped in a `try...finally` block, because in any event that `Get` raises an exception, it will never be free'd, and thus leaking memory.

Comment: Did you set the permissions for your app correctly? Maybe you have simply no permission to access the network.

Comment: @JerryDodge Just edited to put the entire code. I did try, but I removed to make the questions more thin.

Comment: @Wosi That would not justify the fact that it is not working either in win32 where I gave firewall permission. In Android manifet I did `Internet` and `Access Network State`.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I think it's not clear enough that it's not running on any platform when compiled with XE8. Maybe you should clear it up in the question.

Comment: Does it work with the native HttpClients shipped with XE8? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Using_an_HTTP_Client

Comment: @Wosi, Just Tryed. Now it works on win32 but gives me an Error in Android: Access Violation at Address 6222AF78: Read of Address 00000000.

Comment: `Read of Address 0x00000000` is caused by accessing a nil pointer, which means this is now a totally different question. Which line raises that exception? What does the debugger tell you when you set a breakpoint on that line? Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: @KenWhite, The debugger is not working. When I run F9 and it installs the apk, the IDE flips to debugger mode and one second later it turns back to design mode.

Comment: Then put in some logging code so you can figure out when and where you're accessing a nil pointer. It's most likely when accessing a property of something, as in `Something.SomeProp`, where `SomeProp` doesn't exist at the point you're accessing it. We can't debug this aspect of your code, as it may not even be happening here, and we can't inspect the values.

Comment: @KenWhite I did a Tmemo (as shown in the code 'Log.Lines.Add()') to serve as a log and it crashes when I call the procedure (simple procedure) where that code is. I will try to compile it in my house with old Delphi to see if it works.

Comment: Gah! You can't use a TMemo to log. You need to use the Android logging capabilities, so you can inspect things *after the crash*. A `TMemo` would be gone after the crash. You really need to study debugging techniques. :-) See `FMX.Platform.IFMXLoggingService`.

Comment: Thanks, Ken. I will have a look